# Creating a section template

Tags: macros, templates, vim

I'm reading a lot of papers, and writing notes on them as I go. I want to make a single document containing one `\section`  for every `proceedings-year`, with a `\subsection` for every paper. (I'm using `biblatex`).

An example:

```
\section{Proceedings-Year}

\subsection{\citetitle*{foobarbaz}}
\subsubsection{Topics Addressed}
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo
\item Bar
\item FooBar
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Paper Quality}
\textbf{Medium}: This paper is well-written, but foo bar baz blah. 

\subsubsection{Notes}
Some notes on the paper. It might be interesting, or not, or whatever. 

\subsubsection{Citation}
\begin{quote}
\fullcite{foobarbaz}
\end{quote}
\hrulefill
```

I'm happy with the layout, but I don't like copy-pasting this layout every time I want to add another section. (Plus, fiddling with the layout gets very tedious quickly).

What's the best way to automatically insert a copy of this section template? Approaches I can think of:

- Write a macro. However, I have at least 7 bits of text I'd need to pass in (in the given example), more if a paper covers more than 3 topics. (I've never written a macro, and looking at examples I'm not sure this is the best approach).
- Insert automatically (at the editor level). That's fairly easy to do with a `vim` macro, but means if I edit the layout of the section I'll have to edit lots of times.
- Create a new document class. It seems like this could work, but I have no experience doing so, and I think perhaps it's overkill?

I'm not asking for a full solution (although if one is given, I wouldn't complain), but rather the right (easiest? Quickest?) direction to go in to solve this. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Use `emacs`: then you can either use something like [yasnippet](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) if you want to automatically insert a code template and take 'LaTeX'-style notes, or you can use [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) to take notes, which can then be exported to a large number of different formats.  (I prefer `org-mode` for things like note-taking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [UltiSnips](https://github.com/guns/ultisnips) plugin. It
enables you to create snippets that are triggered by a hotkey and expand to
something. There are already plenty of snippets defined, just have a look at
the directory `UltiSnips` file `tex.snippets`,  which work out-of-the-box.
And it's easy to create new ones. Here is an example of an existing snippet:

```
snippet enum "Enumerate" b
\begin{enumerate}
        \item $0
\end{enumerate}
endsnippet
```

This one is triggered by typing `enum` at the beginning of a line followed by
pressing `tab`. You can define several jump positions with `$0`, `$1`, etc. which can be addressed by hitting `tab` once more.

There are other plugins which serve a similar purpose. The advantage of a
general solution is that you can use it for everything, not only for TeX.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you use texmaker. It offers you unlimited number of snippets. Look out for `Unlimited number of snippets` at the bottom of the page -- [texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) and a demo video at [youtube](http://youtu.be/UxCx78bgCTY) or refer to texmaker manual section 4.4.

[image]

1. Click on the user symbol encircled with red in the above picture.
2. right click on the area under `parenth` in the picture to get `Add tag` etc. Choose `Add tag`
3. The `Edit User Tags` window will open. Write in your snippet as shown in the picture. The content to be filled should be indicated by `@`. For your case you may use:

Item -->

```
sect
```

LaTeX Content -->

```
\section{Proceedings-Year}

\subsection{\citetitle*{foobarbaz}}
\subsubsection{Topics Addressed}
\begin{itemize}
\item @
\item @
\item @
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Paper Quality}
\textbf{Medium}: @

\subsubsection{Notes}
@

\subsubsection{Citation}
\begin{quote}
\fullcite{foobarbaz}
\end{quote}
\hrulefill
```

and Keyboard Trigger as

```
 sect
```

Press `OK` to get an item `sect` as shown below. Clicking this will produce the snippet with `•` which has to be replaced by your text. You can move to the next `•` by pressing  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  and in reverse by  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Tab</kbd> .

[image]

You can also activate this by typing `:sect` and pressing  <kbd>→</kbd> .

Comment: The OP clearly states that he uses `vim`. Why do you assume he uses texmaker?

Comment: @Marco Because I am a Physicist ;-)